# MySQL Replace functionality

Tags: mysql, replace

Hi I have a database that lists expiration dates etc...

```
5-22-2012
5-22-2012
5-22-2012
5-22-2012
```

but some came out like

```
5-22-1912
5-22-1912
5-22-1912
```

is there a way to REPLACE just those years at the end of my columns?

Comment: its DATE - I had to repair our database somehow a 9th of our patients turned up with these invalid expiration dates

Comment: As to why and how these values got into the table in the first place, check the insert procedure (form, webpage, whatever). Probably it doesn't have to do with MySQL as default MySQL behaviour is *"#

Dates containing two-digit year values are ambiguous because the century is unknown. MySQL interprets two-digit year values using the following rules:

    *

      Year values in the range 00-69 are converted to 2000-2069.
    *

      Year values in the range 70-99 are converted to 1970-1999.

"*.

Comment: (from: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If field is `DATE` type:

```
--- Add 100 years when date is before 1940

UPDATE TableX
SET expirationDate = expirationDate + INTERVAL 100 YEAR
WHERE expirationDate < '1940-01-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table 
SET thiscolumn = CONCAT(month(thiscolumn),'-', day(thiscolumn),'-2012')
WHERE year(thiscolumn) = '1912';
```